# Line numbers in StackTrace disappear after seeing them only once

Tags: .net, visual-studio

When I output the StackTrace to figure out which line the error occurred on I can see the line number the first time I do it:

```
? ex.StackTrace

"...at Scripts2.Net.clsScripts.CO_VCP() in D:\Dropbox\MapHazardsPro Projects\Scripts_2022\clsScripts.vb:line 14711"
```

But when I do the same thing on subsequent errors in the same debug session:

```
? ex.StackTrace

"...at Scripts2.Net.clsScripts.MI_LUST()"
```

Any idea what I might be doing to cause this?